# redux-saga take with regular expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I'm making use of `redux-saga` for my web app, however I've hit a point where I want to be able to create a single `saga` that handles multiple different request types. In order to do this I want to be able to use `take` or `takeEvery` with a reg-ex. For example:

```
'foo/SOME_REQUEST'
'bar/SOME_REQUEST'
'baz/SOME_REQUEST'
```

Should all be handled through something like so:

```
yield takeEvery('*/SOME_REQUEST', handler);
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or how it can be achieved?

Comment: Looking at the source (https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/proc.js#L22-L29) it looks as though the matcher can be a function, so you should be able to `yield takeEvery(predicateFn, handler);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code for that.

Demo: http://kuy.github.io/redux-saga-examples/takex.html
GitHub: https://github.com/kuy/redux-saga-examples/tree/master/takex

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
yield takeLatest( action => /SOME_REQUEST$/.test(action.type), handler)
```

or

```
yield take( action => /SOME_REQUEST$/.test(action.type))
```

as pointed out here by @lukehedger: [github issue](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/392)

Check the doc: [take(pattern)](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#takepattern)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a custom effect.

```
 //effect.js
    
 export const takeEveryRegex = (pattern, saga, ...args) =>
  fork(function* () {
    while (true) {
      const action = yield take("*")
      if (pattern.test(action.type)) {
        yield fork(saga, ...args.concat(action))
      }
    }
  })
```

Then in your saga, use it according to normal patterns.

```
//saga.js    

function* formFailureSaga({ payload, action }) {
  yield console.log("form failure SAGA", payload, action)
}
    
export function* watchFormFailureSaga() {
  yield takeEveryRegex(/^FAILURE[/s/S]*((?=.*FORM))/, formFailureSaga)
}
```